# What is the difference of "There is/are" in this context

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. There are 6 million accidents per year in the US
> 2. There is 6 million accidents per year in the US

If both they are wrong, then what is the difference between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The singular verb form **is** does not seem to agree with the plural subject, so the first sentence is the correct one.